# ELK installation on Amazon Linux to analyze logs from s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, elastic-stack

I need to setup ELK stack on amazon linux in order to analyze the logs, which are present in the s3 bucket.

I googled a lot before posting this question, but didn't get the proper answer. So please provide me the correct path.
Thanks in adavance!

P.S : I am running only one ec2 instance and not using any load balancers.

Comment: What's the difficulty? There are a lot of ELK stack install guides available.

Comment: @jbird Yeah!! but almost all are using ELB, here I'm using only one ec2 instance. Please provide me links, if u have.  P.S : I am new to this and using amazon linux platform.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this Logz.io guide](http://logz.io/blog/install-elk-stack-amazon-aws/), I found it helpful (slight variations if you're on an AWS Linux).